# How to add the "full screen" button to the title bar on the far right hand side?

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Most Mac applications, including third party ones such as Chrome Browser come with the "Full Screen" icon, placed on the far right side of the title bar.

I would like to do the same thing.

I've done some research but I can not find how to show/hide this button or how to modify the titlebar itself.

Is it not possible? Would I need a complete custom titlebar for this? I don't want to do that to not to lose default window manager's perks.

Thank you

Comment: i googled it and found [a tutorial by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html) among the first hits. why did you not google it

Comment: Hello. As mentioned in my post, I did Google and found that article, amongst others. However I am developing a Qt application, not a Cocoa one and therefore that does not help me really and hence the reason for my question.

Comment: From what i've read, this was going to be added on Qt 5.

Comment: indeed with Qt5 the button is created by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what the **Qt Project** has to say about
[How to handle events in the titlebar and change its color etc?](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_handle_events_in_the_titlebar_and_change_its_color_etc)

> The titlebar belongs to the OS and we don’t have control over that
>   one. You can create your own titlebar, but note that this requires
>   some work. In order to create your own titlebar then make a QWidget
>   [doc.qt.nokia.com] subclass that contains three toolbuttons that
>   handle the close, minimize and maximize events in addition to the
>   moving of the window.